If $X_n\sim\text{Exp }( \lambda_n)$, where $\lambda_n =\lambda+ \frac{\lambda}{n}$, then $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$ where $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda).$
Let $X_1, X_2 ,\dots$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n\sim\text{Exp }( \lambda_n)$, where $\lambda_n  ​ =  \lambda+ \frac{\lambda}{n}$
Show by definition that: $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$  where $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda).$
Given that $X_i$ follows an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda = \frac{1}{\mu}$, the cumulative distribution function $CDF$ of $X_i$  is:
$F_{X_n}(x) = P(X_n \leq x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda_n x}, \quad \text{for } x \geq 0.$
Substituting  $\lambda_n$  with  $\lambda + \frac{\lambda}{n}$ in the above expression, we get:
$F_{X_n}(x) = 1 - e^{-(\lambda + \frac{\lambda}{n})x} = 1 - e^{-\lambda_x} \times e^{\frac{-\lambda_x}{n}}.$
Now, we analyze the limit of  $F_n(x)$ as $n$ tends to infinity:
$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} F_n(x) = \lim_{{n \to \infty}}  (1 - e^{-\lambda_x} \times e^{\frac{-\lambda_x}{n}})$
so:
$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} e^{-\lambda x / n} = e^0 = 1$
and so:
$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} F_n(x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$.
This expression is exactly the CDF of a random variable $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$.
Am i right in my demonstration? I'm missing something?

If you are defining convergence in distribution as convergence of sequence the cumulative distributions $F_{X_n}$ your random variables $X_n$ (at the points of continuity of the propose limiting distribution $F$) then your argument is correct. There is a general definition of convergence in distribution of probability measures that implies convergence in the sense you are describing, but it is not clear from your posting if you are aware of the more general definition.

You proof is right, up to a small detail. You showed the pointwise convergence of the cumulative distribution function on the non-negative real line. Although it is trivial, one should not forget to mention the pointwise convergence of $F_{X_n}(\cdot)$ to $0$ on the negative real line.
By the way, the convergence in distribution would hold if $\lambda_n\to\lambda$, without the special form in the opening post.
